# Selenium ChromeDriver on Jenkins throwing Chrome Version error when executing tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, google-chrome-headless

I am attempting to run my Selenium automated tests on Jenkins so tests will run when I build to Dev. I am executing the tests using Nunit3 Console, so I added a Windows batch command in Jenkins to run the nunit3-console.exe then call my Selenium tests .dll file. All of this seems to work, however, when I run a build on Jenkins I get the following error when my Selenium tests are executed:

Error :

> Selenium.UI.Tests.LoginPage.CanClickLoginButton.Click_Login_Button
>   System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version
>   of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79 (SessionNotCreated)

I am executing my tests as headless and am using the latest version of Chrome Webdriver, 79.0.3945.3600. Since I am running headless I assume I don't need to launch Chrome on my build server, so I am surprised I am getting a versioning error. Am I wrong in this assumption? I am fairly new to Selenium/Jenkins so maybe there is a better way to implement the tests to run on Jenkins?

Comment: Did you try updating Chrome to the version specified in the error?

Comment: I don't believe my build server has Chrome on it. My assumption was that since I am running headless I wouldn't need a version of Chrome at all.

Comment: Here is some reading that might be useful. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

Answer (score 1):

This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79 means you have to install version 79 of chrome